# Named-pipe Error: Unable to create named pipe w/err 0x0000007b

Tags: c++

**Unable to create named pipe w/err 0x0000007b**

I am getting the above error when I try to connect the server and client on different machines.

The code I got from MSDN Link: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppNamedPipeCommunication-7447a0bf

I am using Windows 7 machines to communicate.

**#define FULL_PIPE_NAME      L"\\\\.\\pipe\\SamplePipe"**

To communicate with different machines I changed the above line to:

**#define FULL_PIPE_NAME      L"\\\\My Machine's IP address\\pipe\\SamplePipe"**

Note: In the same machine itself, it will work only if the path is  : L"\\\\.\\pipe\\SamplePipe". It will give the same error if I provide the same machine's IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 0x0000007B is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect").  [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365783.aspx).  When the server calls `CreateNamedPipe()`, it **must** use the `"\\.\pipe\SamplePipe"` name only, as it cannot create a pipe on another machine.  When a client connects to the pipe, it can use the `"\\ServerName\pipe\SamplePipe"` name if connecting to a pipe on a remote or local machine, or the `"\\.\pipe\SamplePipe"` name only if connecting to a pipe on the local machine.  The client cannot use the server's IP Address, it has to use the server's network machine name instead.